# There is no store type corresponding to the conceptual side type 'Geography' of primitive type 'Geography'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

This error occurs on a pretty straightforward MVC 5 site using Entity Framework 6 in a code first implementation. Several of the models use  System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography like the following model.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

namespace ProjectName.Models
{
    public class PostalCode
    {
        [Key]
        [MaxLength(10)]
        public string PostalCodeValue { get; set; }
        public int Country { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(2)]
        public string StateAbbr { get; set; }
        public DbGeography Geo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

During the production move to an external test environment we receive the following error:

```
There is no store type corresponding to the conceptual side type 'Geography' of primitive type 'Geography'.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This error is a bit misleading. In our case, the connection string pointed to the database for the previous version of the site which was older than SQL2012.

The reason this occurs is because the database targeted is not capable of handling this data type. If you receive this verify that the connection string targets the correct database and that it is capable of the data type the error specifies.